# Mongoid embedded documents not maintaining reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid3

So this behavior is counter to what I would have expected. Let's say I have a document that has 1-n embedded images (well, the metadata for the images).  I notice that if I do this:

```
doc.images.first.alt = 'some alt text'
doc.save
```

everything works as normal.  If I first get a ref to the image:

```
i = doc.images.first
i.alt = 'some alt text'
doc.save # and/or i.save
```

The alt text is not saved.  Is that the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning docs.images.first to a var means you are changing that variable, not the originating object.

Think of it like a nested hash

```
a = { x: 1, y: { z: 3 }}
```

If you set:

```
b = a[:y]
```

Changing stuff in b does not affect a.

Comment: I guess I would have expected it to be a reference to the same location in memory, rather than a copy by value. Thanks.